# How would i separate an answer in Kotlin do print 2 different types

Tags: kotlin, type-conversion

Hi this is my first ever program I'm tryin to write in android studio/Kotlin and I'm not sure how to proceed.

so in my program i have a few math tasks to do and it does it fine but what I need to do now is separate part of the answer then covert it then print out both parts

for example if my answer was 1.5232 i would like to convert the decimal part of the answer to a string that matches a range if its in it. the ranges I have are in the .0000 area so I would like to limit the decimal range too.

so final result would look like this

1 (whatever my string in range is)

I hope I included enough info thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what this range is? I don't know what a range of strings would represent or what it would mean to be in a range of Strings. Usually a range is of something quantifiable like numbers. Maybe you can give a complete example of an actual input and desired output.

Comment: my goal is to set ranges and set those ranges to display a fraction 
in 0.0625..0.1874 -> println("1/8")
something like this

Comment: Oh, so you want to display a fraction using some precision like nearest one-eighth?

Comment: Yes ! exactly but id like to also display the full number if there is one. sorry I'm very very green at this but figured I'd try this out. I'm learning programming on my own

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the task is to split the number into the integer and fractional components:

```
val input = 1.5232

val integer = input.toInt() // rounds DOWN to nearest smaller Int
val fractional = input % 1.0 // The remainder when dividing by 1.0 is the fraction
```

The strategy I would use to round to the nearest fractional value given a certain precision is to multiply by that precision, and round to the nearest integer. That would give you the numerator, and the precision would be the denominator:

```
val denominator = 8 // fractional precision
val numerator = (fractional * denominator).roundToInt() // rounds up or down to nearest Int
```

Then to put it together, you can use a string template:

```
val result = "$integer $numerator/$denominator"
println(result)
```

Simplifying the fraction would be another task if you need that. You can find various algorithms for finding greatest common divisor of two numbers. Use one of those and divide the numerator and denominator by that value.

Comment: Also, if the numerator equals the denominator, it might make more sense to drop the fraction and increment the integer part of the number by 1.